# How to configure log4j2.xml log level for specific class only?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

In `log4j` it's possible to define log levels by `package` as follows:

```
    <logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation" level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
    </logger>
```

Questin: how can I define the logging for a specific class only? (eg `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.EndpointHandlerMapping`)?  If I just put this into the `<logger name` property, nothing is logged anymore.

Comment: Is there anything logged from that class when you do get anything logged?

Comment: Yes if course it is.

Comment: Then I guess it actually should work. Have you triple checked your spelling?

Comment: This worked only if I used 'Logger' not 'logger' and 'Console' not 'CONSOLE'

Answer (score 11):

It should work with fully qualified name as well. Logger.name doesn't have to be package/class only but it could be any name which you want to. When you call LoggerFactory.getLogger("MyLogger"), then you have to use

```xml
<Logger name="MyLogger" level="info">
  <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
</Logger>
```

Check what is logged when you use logger for package and use logger name from log.
What logger name is logged for this class?

Comment: The logger name is `o.s.w.s.m.m.a.EndpointHandlerMapping` which is the spring-boot way of abbreviating the logger package name.

Comment: I would try to use
<Logger name="o.s.w.s.m.m.a.EndpointHandlerMapping" level="info">
  <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
</Logger>

Comment: @membersound - Are you sure that it's spring-boot that's doing the abbreviation?  Log4J2 has an option in the logging format to abbreviate the logger source in that way, but that's only an output option not a change in the actual logger name.